# Converting .swf files to animated gifs in Java

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, pdf

I have a bunch of banner files in .swf format. I ultimately want to place these inside a pdf using Java. I have been successful in putting jpegs inside a pdf in Java so far.

I want to know the following things:

1. Is it possible to place the banner files(.swf) in a pdf using either standard java or an external library.
2. If the above is not possible, is it possible to convert these files into animated gifs(again with standard/external java libraries) and put it in the pdf.
3. I would atleast like to extract a frame from these .swf files and use it as a jpeg in my PDF.

Comment: I was going to recommend http://www.swftools.org but it looks like they only support animated gif to swf, not swf to gif.

Answer (score 0):

Some PDF reader may read the swf, like Acrobat, but most won't.

You'd better be converting them.

Here is some external tools that can help you in the process: http://www.swftools.org/

As of making that with native java, it is possible, but it would require re-rendering all the SWF vector drawing, which is a quite heavy work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems like swftools cant be used for this purpose. I tried to use https://code.google.com/p/javaswf9/ . It did create thumnails, however the output was not as expected. I even tried http://www.flagstonesoftware.com/transform/ , without any success. I now only want to extract the last frame in the swf file as a jpeg or png. Please let me know if there is any other way to do this.